# Spring integration file inbound adapter is getting closed while using spring cloud task

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

I have developed a sample spring batch integration [sample](https://github.com/kiranreddykasa/spring-integration-batch) which polls a directory and trigger a batch job for each file.

It's working as expected as long as I am not using spring cloud task.

If I am adding `@EnableTask` to batch configuration file poller is getting stopped because of which application itself is getting stopped.

The sample project can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/kiranreddykasa/spring-integration-batch).

For reproducing the issue please un comment `@EnableTask` in `BatchConfiguration` and spring cloud starter dependency in pom.xml.

Comment: I've the same problem right now. Did you find any solutions? Tnx